# Adding values with condition in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to add some values with a condition in GoogleBigQuery

NOTICE: I edited the original question since  it was not accurate enough.

Thanks to the two participants who have tried to help me.
I tried to apply the solutions  kindly suggested by you but I got the same result from the pct column as a result.

Something like this:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZWXG.png)

Here is the more detailed definition:

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biXfM.png)

Columns:

**Shop**: Shop location

**brand**: Brands of cars sold at shoplocation

**sales**: sales of each brand sold at each shop_location
**rank**: Rank of each brand per shop location (the biggest the greater)

**total_sales_shop**: SUM of all brand sales per shop location

**pct**: percentage of sales by brand in relationship with shop location 
pct_acc:

What i need to calc is **pct_acc which** is the cumulative sum of the shops by rank (while it has no relation with brand)

[**PCT_ACC**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRnh.png)

My need is to reach something like [**PCT_ACC**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRnh.png), and  then save the results in another one like this:[**endtable**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/635Ul.png)

Comment: instead of links to images - please provide input and expected output as a text so we can better help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query to get the required data:

```
select values, rank, 
sum(case when rank<2 then values else 0 end) condition1

from table
group by values, rank
```

Need to add/remove columns from select and group by as per requirement

To get the cumulative sum you can use following query:

```
select shop, brand, sales, rank, total_sales_shop, pct , 
sum(pct) over (partition by shop order by rank) as pct_act
from data
```

And to get the final table you can use combination of case statement and group by

e.g

```
select shop,
max(case when rank=1 then pct_act end) as rank_1,
max(case when rank=2 then pct_act end) as rank_2,
max(case when rank=3 then pct_act end) as rank_3,
max(case when rank=4 then pct_act end) as rank_4,
max(case when rank=5 then pct_act end) as rank_5
from cumulative_sum
group by shop
```

Comment: Sandesh Thank you for your response. I tried it but i got a kind of duplicate of one column. I think it was because of my lack of explanatory ability. Thank you for your response. And sorry by side...

Comment: @ÁlvaroDeAndrés Updated my answer to consider your new requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the final sum for the rows with that condition you can try:

```
SELECT  
   SUM (IF(Rank < 2, Values, 0) AS condition1 
FROM table
```

If you want to get the rank and the sum only for the rows with that condition you can try doing

```
SELECT  
   Rank,
   SUM (IF(Rank < 2, Values, 0) AS condition1 
FROM table
WHERE
   RANK < 2
GROUP BY  
   Rank
```

Finally, if you want to get the rank and the sum considering all the rows you can try doing:

```
SELECT  
   Rank,
   SUM (IF(Rank < 2, Values, 0) AS condition1 
FROM table
GROUP BY  
   Rank
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I tried to apply it but I think the example I had given was not the one I applied in this case. I can only thank you for your help and apologize for the feeling of frustration it may have generated. Thank you very much again and sorry